# AJAX or socket.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sockets, websocket

I am currently making a script, which should work as following:
When you click a button the knob next to the button should insert a value. This have to be done in real time.
So, now I would like to know what I should use for this. I researched a little and came up with ajax or socket.io, but which is better?

Some code:

```
<input class="knob" value="0" readonly data-width="80%">

<div class="button">
<a class="md-btn md-btn-success">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Animation for knob:

```
<input class="knob animated" value="0" readonly data-width="80%" rel="<?php echo $number; ?>">

<script>
       $('.knob').each(function () {

           var $this = $(this);
           var myVal = $this.attr("rel");
           $this.knob({});

           $({
               value: 0
           }).animate({

               value: myVal
           }, {
               duration: 2000,
               easing: 'swing',
               step: function () {
                   $this.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');

               }
           })

       });
</script>
```

I got the animation for the knob in another file and it works when I refresh, so I just have to get it into the real page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

With clever [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) you can try to simulate real time. Otherwise [websocket](/questions/tagged/websocket) is the way to go.

Based on one of the comments on my answer you may be interested in the Javascript framework [socket.io](/questions/tagged/socket.io)

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

> WebSockets is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an
>   interactive communication session between the user's browser and a
>   server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive
>   event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

See this example pulled from [WebSocket](https://www.websocket.org/) that will definitely help you get started.

```js
 var wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/";
 var output;

 function init() {
  output = document.getElementById("output");
  testWebSocket();
 }

 function testWebSocket() {
  websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
  websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
   onOpen(evt)
  };
  websocket.onclose = function(evt) {
   onClose(evt)
  };
  websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
   onMessage(evt)
  };
  websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
   onError(evt)
  };
 }

 function onOpen(evt) {
  writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
  doSend("WebSocket rocks");
 }

 function onClose(evt) {
  writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
 }

 function onMessage(evt) {
  writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data + '</span>');
  websocket.close();
 }

 function onError(evt) {
  writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
 }

 function doSend(message) {
  writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
  websocket.send(message);
 }

 function writeToScreen(message) {
  var pre = document.createElement("p");
  pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
  pre.innerHTML = message;
  output.appendChild(pre);
 }
 window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

```html
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You do realize that socket.io is a high-level abstraction over websockets that have automatic fall-back to long-polling (comet) don't you?

Comment: not sure i would recommend socket.io (or sockets in general) to someone with PHP code in the question...

Comment: @dandavis, I am not seeing any PHP code in here, or in the tags

Comment: maybe you need a bigger screen, it is partially cut-off ;) `<?php echo $number; ?>">` yeah, you _can_ do websockets in php, but something tells me OP would have trouble getting that to work...

Comment: @dandavis, Ah :D -- I am curious why you would not recommend sockets however. If you want to explain it a bit in a chat I'd be happy to pick your brain

Comment: unlike node.js, sockets in php is hard, and won't work out of the box on cheap hosts. I've found EventSource is a much simpler way to push info out of vanilla PHP in real-time, and with IE polyfills now out there, it's a production-ready transport.

Comment: Right on. There is definitely more than one way to skin a cat. I am not personally involved in either technique you mentioned so sharing your knowledge would help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/";
 var output;

 function init() {
  output = document.getElementById("output");
  testWebSocket();
 }

 function testWebSocket() {
  websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
  websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
   onOpen(evt)
  };
  websocket.onclose = function(evt) {
   onClose(evt)
  };
  websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
   onMessage(evt)
  };
  websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
   onError(evt)
  };
 }

 function onOpen(evt) {
  writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
  doSend("WebSocket rocks");
 }

 function onClose(evt) {
  writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
 }

 function onMessage(evt) {
  writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data + '</span>');
  websocket.close();
 }

 function onError(evt) {
  writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
 }

 function doSend(message) {
  writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
  websocket.send(message);
 }

 function writeToScreen(message) {
  var pre = document.createElement("p");
  pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
  pre.innerHTML = message;
  output.appendChild(pre);
 }
 window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

```html
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
```